# Magento, showing payment of a product conditions on the homepage

Tags: php, magento, payment

have a phtml file riding the payment of the value of a product, the function responsible for it automatically puts on every page of the product installment conditions, but does not appear the payment terms on the homepage where I coloto one "carousel "for featured products.

Someone would have a hint of what I do?

Note 1: I use a AllPago the module to set the conditions only that I can not use the stand for the value that do not have access.

Note 2: according to the source code that assembles the installments for me (file name in magento to find looks like this: allpago_installments / productviewtable.phtml

```
  <?php foreach ($this->getInstallments() as $installment): ?>
        <?php $result = count($this->getInstallments()); ?>
        <?php if($installment->getValue()==$result):?>
        <div class="product-view-parcel">
            <?php echo $installment->getValue() . ' x ' . $installment->getInstallment() . ' ' . $installment->getMessage(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Note 3: a part of the home page code where I try to call the price and conditions (heeding the price appears correctly only the payment terms that do not):

```
<div id="ripplesslider" class="ripplesslider" style="height: 470px!important;">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection_slider as $_product): ?>
        <div id="slide" style="text-align: center !important;height: 470px!important;"
             class="latest-slider-item slide slider<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
               title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
                <div style="height: 200px!important;">
                    <img onmouseover="mouseover(<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>)"
                         onmouseout="mouseout(<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>)"
                         style="width:<?php echo $t ?>px;
                             height:<?php echo $imageheight ?>px; "
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/>
                </div>
            </a>

            <div class="desc-item">

                <div class="carousel-name-product"> <?php echo $_product->getName() ?></div>
                <div class="latest-price">

                    <?php if ($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php  $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php echo '<span czlass="price">' . str_replace('R$','', $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)) . '</span>'; ?>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha staff already got, I'll post here what I did to perhaps help others.

```
<div>
                                <?php echo '<span class="price">' . str_replace('R$','', $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)) . '</span>'; ?>
                                <?php // object reference?>
                                <?php $reference = Mage::getStoreConfig('allpago/installments/active'); ?>
                                <?php//returns a new object. references ?>
                                <?php $installmentModel = Mage::getModel('installments/'.$reference); ?>
                                <?php //access the parameters to get the conditions have to function "getInstallmentHighest" to return the plots?>
                                <?php $installmentModel->setValue($_product->getFinalPrice()); ?>
                                <?php $installment = $installmentModel->getInstallmentHighest(); ?>

                                <span style="text-align: left;color: #A8A0A8;position: absolute;margin-top: -46px !important;margin-left: -78px !important;font-size: 12px;">
                                    <?php echo $installment->getValue().' x '. $installment->getInstallment() . ' ' . $installment->getMessage(); ?>
                                </span>


                            </div>
```